# Resolve relative paths in NodeJS/Express

Tags: html, node.js, express, path, redirect

I have a web calling several scripts, images, styles, etc., in different folders (inside and outside the main folder):

**File tree**

```
- /
  - website
      - scripts
        - data.js
        - customJquery.js
      - styles
        - animate.css
      index.html
      main.css
      back.jpg
  - otherFunctions.js
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,400i,800,800i">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster+One">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/animate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class="fondo" src="back.jpg">

        <div class="content">
            <!-- stuff... -->
        </div>

        <script src='scripts/data.js'></script>
        <script src='scripts/customJquery.js'></script>
        <script src='../otherFunctions.js'></script> <!-- Here's the conflict... -->
    </body>
</html>
```

All paths are routed ok, except for `../otherFunctions.js`. It seems that NodeJS/Express skips de relative part `..` and only receives `/otherFunctions.js` which is handled wrongly.

Here's my server side:

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

const config = require('./config');

var webId;

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(config.paths.certificate.key),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(config.paths.certificate.crt),
  requestCert: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin, X-Requested-With");
  next();
});

app.get('/favicon.ico', function(req, res) {
  res.status(404).send('No favicon found');
});

app.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  id = req.params.id;

  if (id.search(/\w+\.[A-z]+$/g) < 0) {
    webId = id;
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: config.paths.webs + id});
  } else {
    res.sendFile(id, {root: config.paths.webs});
  }
});

app.get('/:folder/:file', function(req, res) {
  let folder = req.params.folder;
  let file = req.params.file;

  res.sendFile(file, {root: config.paths.webs + webId + '/' + folder});
});


app.get('*', (request, response) => {
  response.send('GET request not found: ' + request.url);
});


app.use((err, request, response, next) => {
  response.status(500).send(err.message);
});

https.createServer(options, app).listen(443, function() {
  console.clear();
  console.log("NodeJS secure server started at port 443");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific need to serve your static files this way, I'd suggest using the express built-in [static file serving](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Regarding the use of '../otherFunctions.js' in your HTML, I'm afraid the browser tries to resolve the path relative to the position of the HTML file itself, so for example, if the HTML file was `my.domain.com/foo/bar/index.html`, the browser would be looking for `my.domain.com/foo/otherFunctions.js`. Ideally, all the static files you want to serve to the client should be in one folder that is then used by the `express.static(...)` call.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure I can change the way I serve the elements. Since I'm just creating the server in NodeJS, the webs are located in an specific folder in the system which I can't change.
In the other hand, I'm looking for the behaviour you described, but I'm not getting the call `../otherFunctions.js` in server, just `/otherFunctions.js`.

Comment: That's because `http://foo.com/../bar` gets automatically resolved to `http://foo.com/bar` by the browser. I'm afraid you'll need to find a different way to structure and serve your static files.

Comment: I wish I could, but it's not in my hand... Guess I will have to hardcode some things.